# How do you get rid of double quotes from "name" and "count" from the console output in JavaScript?

Tags: javascript, arrays, string, output, console.log

I have trouble turning the input:

["apple", "banana", "carrot", "durian", "eggplant", "apple", "carrot"]
into the right output:

[{ name: "Apple", count: 2 }, { name: "Banana", count: 1 }, { name: "Carrot", count: 2 }, { name: "Durian", count: 1 }, { name: "Eggplant", count: 1 }],
where I have trouble with the wrong output:

[{"name":"Apple","count":2},{"name":"Banana","count":1},{"name":"Carrot","count":2},{"name":"Durian","count":1},{"name":"Eggplant","count":1}].
How can I have the right output:

[{ name: "Apple", count: 2 }, { name: "Banana", count: 1 }, { name: "Carrot", count: 2 }, { name: "Durian", count: 1 }, { name: "Eggplant", count: 1 }]
with the use of console.log() method?

```
    <html>
    <body>
    <script>
    var input = ["apple", "banana", "carrot", "durian", "eggplant", "apple", "carrot"];
    
    var A = 0;//to count the number of apples
    var B = 0;//to count the number of bananas
    var C = 0;//to count the number of carrots
    var D = 0;//to count the number of durians
    var E = 0; //to count the number of eggplants

     for (var i = 0; i < input.length; i++)
      {
         if (input[i] == "apple")
         {   
           A += 1;  
          }
         if (input[i] == "banana")
         {   
           B += 1;  
          }
         if (input[i] == "carrot")
         {   
           C += 1;  
          }
         if (input[i] == "durian")
         {   
           D += 1;  
         }
         if (input[i] == "eggplant")
         {   
           E += 1;  
         }
       }            

    let x1 = { name: 'Apple', 
               count: A };
    let x2 = { name: 'Banana', 
               count: B };
    let x3 = { name: 'Carrot', 
               count: C };
    let x4 = { name: 'Durian', 
               count: D };
    let x5 = { name: 'Eggplant', 
               count: E };

   var output = [];
   output.push(x1);
   output.push(x2);
   output.push(x3);
   output.push(x4);
   output.push(x5);

   console.log("output = ", output);
   document.getElementById('output').innerHTML = JSON.stringify(output);

   </script>
   </body>
   </html>
```

Comment: Welcome to SO! Please read the guide on how to ask a question https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Comment: The correct syntax for JSON is to place inverted commas around the properties. So if you don't want them, don't use JSON.stringify

Comment: @user2871050 Have you tried regex solution?

Answer (score -1):

You can use regular expression like below:

```
var yourStringifiedResult = "[{\"name\":\"Apple\",\"count\":2},{\"name\":\"Banana\",\"count\":1},{\"name\":\"Carrot\",\"count\":2},{\"name\":\"Durian\",\"count\":1},{\"name\":\"Eggplant\",\"count\":1}]";

yourStringifiedResult = yourStringifiedResult.replace(/"(\w+)"\s*:/g, '$1:');
console.log(yourStringifiedResult);
```

Working sample:

```js
var yourStringifiedResult = "[{\"name\":\"Apple\",\"count\":2},{\"name\":\"Banana\",\"count\":1},{\"name\":\"Carrot\",\"count\":2},{\"name\":\"Durian\",\"count\":1},{\"name\":\"Eggplant\",\"count\":1}]";

yourStringifiedResult = yourStringifiedResult.replace(/"(\w+)"\s*:/g, '$1:');
console.log(yourStringifiedResult);
```

Answer (score -1):

Just add this line after push the all objects in array:

```
let outputInString = "";

for (let fruit of input) outputInString += "Name: " + fruit.name + ", Count: " + fruit.count + ", ";

document.getElementById('output').innerHTML = outputInString;
```